# OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'fr_core_web_md'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy

I am working on NLP project so I am using spacy, the problem is when I `import nlp=spacy.load('fr_core_news_md')`, it doesn't work for me and I get this error:

> OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'fr_core_news_md'. It doesn't seem to
> be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data
> directory."

Despite the use of `python -m spacy download fr_core_news_md`

Comment: What is the output of `os.path.dirname(spacy.__file__)`. This should contain all the data. In your case it should be under `fr\data`

Comment: It doesn't have to be in `spacy/data` – models are Python packages, so they can also be loaded directly from the package name. If you run `pip list`, the `fr_core_news_md` model should show up there. If not, it may indicate that it wasn't installed in the same environment you're using when you run your spaCy code.

Comment: My solution for the Greek language found here https://spacy.io/models/el

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem and here's what worked for me:

Downloaded with `python3 -m spacy download fr_core_news_md`

```
import spacy
import fr_core_news_md

nlp = fr_core_news_md.load()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yet, How would you do if you needed it in a library?

Answer (score 3):

Type:

`!python -m spacy download fr_core_news_md`  fom your Jupyter or Colab cell.

[image]

`Restart Runtime` or `[Cntrl+M]` from the Menu bar on top.

---

You can also check the version and compatibility of all your downloaded packages in spacy with this command:

`!python -m spacy validate`

[image]

Make sure to  `Restart Runtime` after each download.

Answer (score 2):

It is worth mentioning the bug I had recently.

- I installed the `fr_core_news_md`, and then I tried to load the `fr_core_news_sm.`

It was around 2:00 AM I wasn't able to find it.

I slept and came back in the morning and found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

first install the package then import it (but not vice versa)

first : `!python3 -m spacy download fr_core_news_md`

then : `nlp = spacy.load("fr_core_news_md")`

Answer (score 1):

if you use anaconda jupyter Notebook then just run this code and will be solved:

```
`conda install -c conda-forge spacy-model-de_core_news_sm`
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).